# How to access function value in another function in PHP Classes

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can i return a variable value from one function and pass it to another function in a class and access it ?, im new to php class.

here is the code i have tried

```
<?php
class BioTool{
public function one(){
$lol =[2,3,5]; print_r($lol);
}
 public function two(){
     $newarr=$this->one(); //this only return the array but i can't access it, check below.
    print_r($newarr[0]); //not working
}
}

$biotool=new BioTool();
$biotool->two();
```

Comment: Your class doesn't have a function called check().

Comment: Hi I have corrected the question, please check @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 )
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/u483428433/domains/ytsubme.com/public_html/ ...on line 8

Comment: Ok thanks. Your one() method doesn't have a return statement. You need `return $lol;` at the end of it.

Comment: Thank you somuch @ADyson, ,its working now. :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), i had to return  from the function instead of echo.

```
<?php
class BioTool{
public function one(){
    print_r($lol);
return $lol =[2,3,5]; 

}
 public function two(){
     $newarr=$this->one();
    print_r($newarr[0]); // working
}
}

$biotool=new BioTool();
$biotool->two();
```